# C# Using WIPMania in Application

Tags: c#, geolocation

Hey im trying to use the WIPMania Geolocation database in my C# application but i really don't know how to it...

I'm looking for a way without having to include external libraries if possible...

http://www.wipmania.com/en/base/

There are some different formats availible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i'm now using a local SQLCE database which i also need for the rest of my application.

I imported the data from the .sql files and now it should work...

But in VisualStudio 2008 the performance of database queries in VS itself (not in the program) is sooo slow. 50k+ entries take ages to be added or deleted...

Comment: Is there a question or an answer here?